# Why does GregorianCalendar.getTimeInMillis() return wrong value?

Tags: android, android-calendar, gregorian-calendar

I want to calculate time gap in form of days between two dates. So I wrote following code:

```
public static int calculateTimeGap(long start, long end) {
    GregorianCalendar calendar1 = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar1.setTimeInMillis(start);
    System.out.println("calendar1:");
    showCalendar(calendar1);

    GregorianCalendar calendar2 = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar2.setTimeInMillis(end);
    System.out.println("calendar2:");
    showCalendar(calendar2);

    int gap = (int) (end / 86400000 - start / 86400000);
    System.out.println("gap in days:" + gap);
    return gap;
}
```

Here are outputs:

```
03-02 15:28:08.021 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: calendar1:
03-02 15:28:08.021 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: year: 2016
03-02 15:28:08.021 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: month: 3
03-02 15:28:08.021 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: day: 2
03-02 15:28:08.021 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: week: 3
03-02 15:28:08.021 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: hour: 15
03-02 15:28:08.021 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: minute: 28
03-02 15:28:08.021 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: second: 8
03-02 15:28:08.021 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out:  
03-02 15:28:08.021 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: calendar2:
03-02 15:28:08.021 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: year: 2016
03-02 15:28:08.021 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: month: 3
03-02 15:28:08.022 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: day: 3
03-02 15:28:08.022 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: week: 4
03-02 15:28:08.022 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: hour: 1
03-02 15:28:08.022 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: minute: 0
03-02 15:28:08.022 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: second: 0
03-02 15:28:08.022 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out:  
03-02 15:28:08.022 20814-20814/com.ywwynm.everythingdone I/System.out: gap in days:0
```

You can see that two `GregorianCalendar`s present different days, but finally we got a gap equals 0.

The parameters of this method, `start` and `end`, come from following code:

```
GregorianCalendar curCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
long start = curCalendar.getTimeInMillis(); // parameter start

GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(2016, Calendar.MARCH, 3, 1, 0);
long end = calendar.getTimeInMillis(); // parameter end
```

So the behavior is very strange. I thought that `gregorianCalendar.getTimeInMillis()` will always return correct and timezone-independent value so that it can be used as a stable and trustworthy standard to compute and compare time. However, as the code and output shown, it is wrong. And if I considered my timezone(Beijing GMT+8:00), add an offset by `Timezone.getDefault().getRawOffset()` to parameter `start` or minus it to `end`, the result will be correct. But this is actually strange.

What made me get incorrect result?

**UPDATE:**

```
public static void showCalendar(GregorianCalendar calendar) {
    System.out.println("year: "   +  calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    System.out.println("month: "  + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1));
    System.out.println("day: "    +  calendar.get(Calendar.DATE));
    System.out.println("week: "   + (calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1));
    System.out.println("hour: "   +  calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    System.out.println("minute: " +  calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    System.out.println("second: " +  calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

Comment: Define *exactly* what you mean by "gap in form of days", given that the times themselves are expressed in milliseconds. What were you expecting the difference to be, and why?

Comment: @DougStevenson “gap in form of days" means time gap between two different dates in days. If first date is today, second is tomorrow, then their gap is 1. If first is today, second is the day after tomorrow, then their gap is 2. Gap is 0 if these two dates are both today. We only focus on year/month/day and ignore hour/minute/second.

Comment: To avoid confusion, please show your `showCalendar` code, or better yet produce a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can see that two GregorianCalendars present different days, but finally we got a gap equals 0.

Yes, and that's entirely reasonable. You're comparing March 2nd, 15:28:08 with March 3rd, 01:00:00. They're on different dates, but are less than a day apart. There's no problem here.

Heck, you could see the same with two values which are just *one millisecond* apart - they can still be on different dates.

Note that in terms of time zones, by default `GregorianCalendar` will use your system default time zone. The value returned by `getTimeInMillis` will always return the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch, so that's time zone neutral - but the constructor you're calling here:

```
new GregorianCalendar(2016, Calendar.MARCH, 3, 1, 0)
```

... is saying "I want the value representing March 3rd, 1am *local time*" where *local time* means "in your default time zone".

Computing the difference between dates is difficult - I would *very strongly* recommend that you ditch `Calendar` and `Date` entirely, instead using `java.time` if you're using Java 8, or [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) otherwise. Then you can use `LocalDate` to represent a date without a time, and easily find the difference between two dates.

Comment: @ywwynm: I've edited my answer. It doesn't help that you're calling a `showCalendar` method without showing what it does. I assumed it was printing out the result of `calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)` which would show 3 for April, not March. But fundamentally, the answer is still correct - two instants in time on different dates can be less than 24 hours apart.

Comment: So each time when I use `GregorianCalendar.getTimeInMillis()`, I should transform the result into time independent with timezone by myself?

Comment: @ywwynm: I don't know what you mean by "time independent with timezone" and frankly it's very unclear exactly what you're trying to do. I've explained why your code behaves the way it does, and that `GregorianCalendar` is working fine. But as noted in my edited answer, I would suggest you use a better API.

Comment: "time independent with timezone" means this: Like `System.currentTimeInMillis()`, it always returns UTC times, regardless of the system's time zone.

Comment: @ywwynm: Well that's what `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` does, for a given instant in time. But when you construct a `Calendar`, if you don't specify a time zone, any values you provide for month, day etc are interpreted as being in the local time zone. It sounds like *maybe* you just need to pass in the UTC time zone to `Calendar`...

Comment: Yes I know that behavior. But I think `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` will also return a time regardless of time zone even it is constructed with local time zone... Is this wrong?

Comment: @ywwynm: Yes, as I said, `calendar.getTimeInMillis()` will return the same value for the same *instant in time*. But that same instant in time will have different local times in different time zones. To reiterate though, I *really* think you should be using java.time or Joda Time.

Comment: Oh, I understand my mistake. If I'm in London, my calculation will be correct. Yes?

Comment: @ywwynm: It's hard to say as I *still* don't understand exactly what you're trying to do. (And London != UTC... in summer time we're UTC+1.)

Comment: I'm trying to know if two UTC times are same date or not considering time zone. In normal time, London's time zone is GMT +0, right? So my method will be correct in London.

Comment: @ywwynm: There's no concept of "not considering time zone" when it comes to converting an instant in time to a date. You can say "in UTC", but that's not the same thing. And again, London is only UTC+0 during winter months... I don't view a method which is only correct in London for half of time as "correct in London".

Comment: Yes, that's not perfect. But I got your idea. Now I change my code to this: `int sOff = Timezone.getDefault().getOffset(start); int eOff = ...; return (end + eOff) / 86400000 - (start + sOff) / 86400000;`

Comment: @ywwynm: No, *don't* do that. Any time you find yourself manually adding offsets, there's almost certainly a better approach. In this case, the better approach is to use a `GregorianCalendar` in the UTC time zone... or ideally, don't use `Calendar` at all.

Answer (score 0):

What you're measuring is not the gap in days, as you define it.  What you're measuring is the number of full 24 hour periods between start and end.

In your example, your end time is actually not a full 24 hours away from the start time.  So your distance in 24 hour periods is 0.

If you want to measure difference in days as defined by the current timezone midnight being the boundary between days, you should instead be comparing the [DAY_OF_YEAR](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_YEAR) and [YEAR](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#YEAR) values of the two Calendar objects.

Comment: I'm afraid you are wrong. If I use (end - start) / 86400000, then I'm measuring number of full 24 hour periods between start and end. By my method, I'm calculating the gap only focusing date. For example, Jan 1st and Jan 2nd, their gap in days is 1, even time1 is 23:59, Jan 1st and time2 is 0:01, Jan 2nd.

Comment: No, your division is rounding *down* in integer math, so it won't hit the value 1 until *after* the first full 24 hour period has been crossed.